# Syntax error for nested condtionals in SQL

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I'm pretty new to redshift and I've been trying to to do a nested case when condition here, yet I get a syntax error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"

in this line of SQL:

```
ELSE ROUND((last_bid * positions), 2))
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, since I'm familiar with Python and I'm pretty sure this is how nested conditions work

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE
       WHEN asset_type = 'EQUITY' 
          THEN (CASE
                   WHEN positions < 0 THEN ROUND((positions * last_ask), 2)
                   ELSE ROUND((last_bid * positions), 2))
          ELSE ROUND((positions * last_ask/100), 2)
    END AS MARKET_VALUE
FROM 
    base_report
```

Comment: You have two CASEs, but only one END

Comment: If any of the answers have resolved the issue, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end the nested CASE, like that:

```
ELSE ROUND((last_bid * positions), 2)
END
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
        
    CASE
    WHEN asset_type = 'EQUITY' THEN
    (
    CASE
    WHEN positions < 0 THEN
    ROUND((positions * last_ask), 2)
    ELSE ROUND((last_bid * positions), 2)
    END )
    ELSE ROUND((positions * last_ask / 100), 2)
    END AS MARKET_VALUE
FROM base_report
```

Please do let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT *

     , CASE
        WHEN asset_type ='EQUITY' THEN 
        (CASE
        WHEN positions < 0 THEN ROUND((positions * last_ask),2)
        ELSE ROUND((last_bid * positions),2) end)
        
        ELSE ROUND((positions * last_ask/100),2)
      END  as MARKET_VALUE

FROM base_report
```